# Maven checkstyle plugin gives error for "Parameter s should be final.", even s is modified

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

We are using maven checkstyle plugin. Below is the pom.xml configuration.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
        <configLocation>sun_checks.xml</configLocation> 
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
        <logViolationsToConsole>true</logViolationsToConsole>
        <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
        <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
        <violationSeverity>error</violationSeverity>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>  
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
        <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions> 
</plugin>
```

We have below java code.

```
package com.comp.teststyleguide;

public class A {

  public A(String s) {
    s = "test1";

  }

}
```

Now, `mvn clean package` gives below console message.

> [ERROR]
>   /work/checkstyle/teststyleguide/src/main/java/com/comp/teststyleguide/A.java:5:12:
>   Parameter s should be final. [FinalParameters]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reassigning method parameter values in a method is not a good programming practice,

> Check that parameters for methods, constructors, and catch blocks are
>   final. Interface, abstract, and native methods are not checked: the
>   final keyword does not make sense for interface, abstract, and native
>   method parameters as there is no code that could modify the parameter.
>
> Rationale: Changing the value of parameters during the execution of
>   the method's algorithm can be confusing and should be avoided. A great
>   way to let the Java compiler prevent this coding style is to declare
>   parameters final.

You can find more information at checkstyle documentation. http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#FinalParameters

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't reassign parameters.

Checkstyle has a separate [ParameterAssignmentCheck](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/coding/ParameterAssignmentCheck.html) for the case you don't want to make your parameters `final`.

From the JavaDoc:

> Disallow assignment of parameters.
>
> Rationale: Parameter assignment is often considered poor programming
>   practice. Forcing developers to declare parameters as final is often
>   onerous. Having a check ensure that parameters are never assigned
>   would give the best of both worlds.